# Query on Jython with Web Start

Tags: jython, java-web-start

I am looking at creating a jython application and deploying it as a java web start.

My query is related to a concern that for web start deployment, we have to distribute the jython standard jar package also along with our application jar.

From all the web resources , this is what I hear. And the concern is that this will make the download time of the application significantly large as jython jar file is nearly 9 Mb.

If anyone of you has deployed a jython app through web start, can you clarify if we need to bundle the jython jar package along with our application files or only the application files in a standalone jar file ( this solves my problem)

Regards
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK , as I figured out...I have to package the jython jar also along with the application jar to make it work.

The reason is that, the application jar consists of python code which the client JVM has no way to understand unless it uses the jython jar package.

As I hear jython has no support currently to convert python code to java classes. Unless this is possible , the jython jar package has to be included.